# Poor image quality Graphics2D.drawImage()

Tags: java, jframe, bufferedimage, drawimage

I'm having some problems drawing images in Java. I have an [image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOfO4.png) file on disk that Java needs to read and then draw. But as a [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpU0V.png), I got a poor quality image, especially double lines.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    BufferedImage bi;

    for(int i = 0; i < 2545; i++) {
    try {
        bi = ImageIO.read(new File("img/img_" + i + ".png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
        g2d.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears that your second image is larger than your first image.  Enlarging any image leads to blurring.  Make sure you're not Windows scaling your GUI.

Comment: Uhm... Why are you reading *2545* PNGs *inside* the `paint()` method...? Don't ever do that! It will make your application extremely sluggish... That said, the quality issue is likely caused by UI scaling, as Gilbert mentioned.